# Closing a Window in WPF (When not in that Window)

Tags: wpf, window

I have an application which starts with a simple start screen allowing the user to select either New or Open a project.  When selecting New I have a new window displayed which is a wizard that collects data to be passed to the Main window.

I create a new Window for the Main window and show that.
Then I close the wizard easily enough with `this.close();`
But how do I close the initial window which is the Startup URI window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Startup window to the main window as a constructor parameter or property, then call `Close()` on it.